# Sequelize can't run seeders due to dialect not detected on config file ("ERROR: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied")

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have a `nodejs` project that uses `sequelizejs` and now the config file as a `config.json` looks like this:

```js
{
    "development": {
        "users": {
            "username": "postgres",
            "password": "admin",
            "database": "users",
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 5432,
            "dialect": "postgres",
            "dialectOptions": {
                "ssl": false,
                "useUTC": false
            },
            "logging": false,
            "timezone": "+08:00"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the `.sequelizerc` file looks like this:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    config: path.resolve('./config/config.json'),
    'models-path': path.resolve('./models'),
    'seeders-path': path.resolve('./seeders'),
    'migrations-path': path.resolve('./migrations'),
}
```

If anyone is wondering, the file tree for my `seeders` folder looks like this:

```
seeders
 ┣ products
 ┣ test1
 ┗ users
 ┃ ┣ 20230206125203-Users.js
 ┃ ┗ 20230206132648-UserProfiles.js
```

I run the command:
`npx sequelize-cli db:seed --seeders-path ./seeders/users --env development.users`

but I received an error:

```bsh
Sequelize CLI [Node: 16.17.0, CLI: 6.6.0, ORM: 6.29.1]

Loaded configuration file "config\config.json".

ERROR: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0
```

My `.env` already has a `NODE_ENV=development` on it.

I read the whole documentation for `sequelize` and it doesn't seem to provide a scenario where `development` has nested values inside of it.

Interestingly, a user from [this](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/1068) GitHub issue on sequelize-cli has a solution to their problem but they used a `config.js`, but I still use `config.json` on the `.sequelizerc` and as I try to mimic their code, it still doesn't work for my case.

I believe the issue here resides in the `config.json` being nested as `development.users` but I don't seem to see anything on the documentation I have missed.

Feel free to answer the question on how can I work to seed my seeder file! Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try `'development.users': {` key instead of nested `development: { user:`?

Comment: to where I would try this exactly?

Comment: in `config.json` of course

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to see how you are using your configurations, based on your set up you should have something similar like the one below:

const config = require('./config.json');

```
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.users.db_name,
    config.users.db_user,
    config.users.password,
    {
      host: config.users.host,
      dialect: config.users.dialect,
      logging: false,
    }
  );
```

or

```
sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], {
    logging: false,
  });
```

in the first option, you have to specify all the options required by Sequelize in the correct order (database name, user, password then options) in the second piece of code, the environment is picked up and then configurations applied based on what environment you are on